# Can I use Windows 10-based PC on a stick as server?

Tags: windows

Right now I’m running an SSH server on a Windows 10 machine with a Core 2 Duo CPU and 4GB of RAM. The SSH server is used by multiple users to run pure text batch files that preform actions like time keeping, mail and link sharing, and weather reports.

I’m wondering if I could switch to something like this [Lenovo Ideacentre Stick 300](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops-and-all-in-ones/ideacentre/stick-300/Stick-300/p/99IC9SP0239) or this [Intel® Compute Stick STCK1A32WFC](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/86612/intel-compute-stick-stck1a32wfc.html) which has 2GB of RAM and runs Windows 10 Home. It’s originally designed for media servers and the like, but would it work for this without much of a performance drop? Is it safe to leave on 24/7?

Comment: In general? Maybe. The reality is small items like that are never designed to run 24/7. A media server does a lot of work but tends to not run 24/7; maybe 5-8 hours a day? The thing is what you describe as “…time keeping, mail and link sharing, and weather reports.” is not a real clear look at resource usage. Any one of those could be CPU or storage intensive. So honestly too broad a question.

Comment: Hmm. Okay thanks. The timekeeping is each second and doesn’t raise cpu much. The weather report will for a second but that’s all. Your answer on 24/7 helps.